# Getting two separateed integer values

Tags: python, arrays, list

Say I have this list  `[[55.0][75.1]]`, how can I turn this into two separated integer variables of `55` and `75`
Thanks in advance

Comment: what kind of a list is this `[[55. 0.][75.1.]]`

Comment: did you try to assign that list to a variable in your code?

Comment: You'd get a `SyntaxError` with that list.

Comment: it is not clear what your numbers are. Are they 55 0 75 1 or 55.0 and 75.1. What is the last '.' there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
k = []
k.append(55.0)
k.append(75.1)
l = [k]
print l

int0 = int(l[0][0])
int1 = int(l[0][1])
print int0
print int1
```

prints:

```
[[55.0, 75.1]]
55
75
```

Comment: Isn't there a missing comma there?

Comment: If you want `int0` to be 55, and `int1` to be 75, then doesn't `l` have to be `[[55.0, 75.1]]`?

Comment: @DSM: I don't understand your comment, l is [[55.0, 75.1]]

Comment: Look at your code. `l = [[55.0][75.1]]`, which isn't valid Python syntax.

Comment: @DSM: Yes you are right ... I meant l would be printed as [[55.0][75.1]] ... just changed the code above including prints and tested.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> [int(Decimal(x[0])) for x in i]
[55, 75]
```

This is the long version:

```
results = []
for x in i:
   int_value = int(Decimal(x[0]))
   results.append(x)
```

Comment: Because you might have other things in there that might not convert so easily.